# Object doesn't support this property or method with If-Then Statement

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm trying to pull information from a data table into an array, but I only want data that matches criteria.  My IF statement keeps throwing this error and it's been giving me a headache for an hour now.  Any advice appreciated!

```
Dim InputArray() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, r As Integer, m As Integer, k As Integer

ReDim InputArray(1 To 798, 1 To 22)

LoopStart:
For m = 1 To 866
    Sheets("Base").Activate
    If Sheets("Base").Cell(m + 1, 23) = 6 Then GoTo Line1 <<This line throws the error


Line1:
    k = UBound(InputArray, 1) + 1
        For j = 1 To 22
            InputArray(k, j) = Sheets("Base").Cell(m + 1, j).Value
        Next j

Next m
'GoTo LoopStart

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, if I try to add ".Value" after "Cell(m+1,23)", I get a different error - "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: You should say `Cells` not `Cell`.

Comment: `Sheets("Base").Activate` is unnecessary.  `Activate` is a slow statement so, if ever required, avoid placing it within a For loop.

Comment: @PaulaMyatt have you tried the code in my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

The code below, only refers to the section of code you uploaded, if you can upload the rest of your `Sub`, maybe a better and cleaner solution can be provided.

Like @Tony Dallimore mentioned, changed `Cell` to `Cells`, also declared `BaseSht As Worksheet` to remove possible errors later, and to later Use `With BaseSht`.

Not sure why you located have `Line1` where you have placed it in your code, even `If .Cells(m + 1, 23).Value = 6` fails, it will still go to the next row, which is `k = UBound(InputArray, 1) + 1` and the `For` loop following that.

If you have shared the structure of your sheet and data, probably could change `For m = 1 To 866` to dynamic **LastRow**, with `For m = 1 To LastRow` , where **LastRow** is a number that changes dynamically with the number of rows data you have.

```
Dim BaseSht         As Worksheet
Dim InputArray()    As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, r As Integer, m As Integer, k As Integer

Set BaseSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base")
ReDim InputArray(1 To 798, 1 To 22)

LoopStart:

With BaseSht
    For m = 1 To 866          
        If .Cells(m + 1, 23).Value = 6 Then GoTo Line1   

Line1:
        k = UBound(InputArray, 1) + 1
        For j = 1 To 22
            InputArray(k, j) = .Cells(m + 1, j).Value
        Next j

    Next m

End With
'GoTo LoopStart
```